# Bitwise operators changing result of arithmetic

Tags: javascript, math, bit-manipulation

Can somebody explain to me why the following code:

```
  var a = 0xFFFFFFFF;
  a &= 0xFFFFFFFF;
  a += 1;
  alert( "a = " + a );

  var b = 0xFFFFFFFF;
  b += 1;
  alert( "b = " + b );
```

returns different values for a and b?

Since 0xFFFFFFFF & 0xFFFFFFFF should equal 0xFFFFFFFF, both pieces of code should return 0x100000000. Instead a get the value of 0 and b get the value of 0x100000000.

Comment: Regarding your last question -- just add `b &= 0xFFFFFFFF` before `b += 1`!

Comment: BTW, what are the results you get for `a` and `b`?

Comment: I shouldn't have to though since 0xFFFFFFFF & 0xFFFFFFFF = 0xFFFFFFFF. They should be the exact same value both times.

Comment: I'm getting 0 for a and 0x100000000 for b.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since JavaScript works with *signed* integers, 4294967295 can't be represented in 32 bits, thus it is converted to a wider type.

```
var a = 0xFFFFFFFF;
alert("a = " + a);  // gives 4294967295 (too large for a signed 32-bit integer)

a &= 0xFFFFFFFF;    // gives result as 32 bit signed integer
alert("a = " + a);  // gives -1
```

Details on the bitwise operators can be found here: [Mozilla Developer Network: Bitwise Operators](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_Operators)

If you initialize `a` to `0xFFFFFFF` (thats 7 `F`s) you get the expected result.

```
var a = 0xFFFFFFF;
alert("a = " + a);   // gives 268435455
a &= 0xFFFFFFFF;
alert("a = " + a);   // gives 268435455
```

Comment: 0xFFFFFFFF isn't too large for a 32-bit integer. It is the largest value a 32-bit integer can hold.

Comment: It still doesn't make sense. 0xFFFFFFFF is a 32-bit integer which is displayed as 4294967295. I then perform a bitwise operator using another 32-bit integer as the second operand. Both are converted to an array of bits to do the and-ing. The result is displayed as a signed integer (-1). Nothing has changed except the way the number is displayed? Why convert an array of bits to a signed integer before doing a bitwise operation? You gave me the answer to my question, but several more questions to ask.

Comment: Right. `0xFFFFFFFF` is not a 32-bit signed integer integer, but a wider type that *can* handle such large numbers. The *result* from a bitwise and, however, is a 32-bit signed integer.

Answer (score 4):

JS bitwise operators return a *signed* 32-bit integer.   0xFFFFFFFF gets converted to -1, and adding 1 gives 0.

Comment: That makes sense. I guess I shouldn't assume that all JavaScript variables are 64-bit.

Comment: JavaScript doesn't actually *have* integers.  It just has numbers, which are implemented as doubles, hence limited to 53 bits of precision (the other 11 bits are used for the exponent).  I've gotten bitten by that fact while querying a database that used 64-bit integers as unique identifiers.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var a = 0xFFFFFFFF;
alert( "a = " + a );
a &= 0xFFFFFFFF;
alert( "a = " + a );
a += 1;
alert( "a = " + a );
```

and it should be a little more apparent what's going on. The `&=` is causing a type conversion that doesn't happen for `b`.

Answer (score 0):

In JavaScript, the following expression is `true`:

```
(0xFFFFFFFF & 0xFFFFFFFF) == -1
```

As said by dan04, the result of boolean operations is a signed 32 bit integer value, independent of the type of the parameters.
When you look at the bit-pattern of 0xFFFFFFFF and of -1, they are identical when using 32-bit values.

To always get positive results, you can add 2^32 to the result when it is negative:

```
function and(a, b) { let y = a & b; return (y < 0) ? (y + 0x100000000) : y;}
```

Then the following expression is `true`:

```
and(0xffffffff, 0xffffffff) == 0xffffffff
```